# get json max count by key

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the maximum number of objects within a key in this case is "child". For each object and sub​​-objects, I want to get to the level achieved by each. Hope you can understand this question. This means a lot to me

For example:

```
[{
    name:"Node Parent 1 Level 0",
    childs:[{
        name:"Sub Node 1 Level 1",
        childs:[{
            name:"Sub Node 1 Level 2"
        }]
    },{
        name:"Sub Node 2"
    },{
        name:"Sub Node 3"
    }]
},{
    name:"Node Parent 2 Level 0",
    childs:[{
        name:"Sub Node 1 Level 1",
        childs:[{
            name:"Sub Node 1 Level 2"
        },{
            name:"Sub Node 2 Level 2",
            childs:[{
                name:"Sub Node 1 Level 3"
            },{
                name:"Sub Node 2 Level 3",
                childs:[{
                    name:"Sub Node 1 Level 4"
                },{
                    name:"Sub Node 2 Level 4"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },{
        name:"Sub Node 2 Level 1",
        childs:[{
            name:"Sub Node 1 Level 2"
        },{
            name:"Sub Node 2 Level 2",
            childs:[{
                name:"Sub Node 1 Level 3"
            },{
                name:"Sub Node 2 Level 3"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The total of "childs" sub nodes for each parent object. Example: "Node Parent 1" or Object1:2, "Node Parent 2" or Object2:3, etc.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this?

Comment: Of course, but problem is I'm overloaded of work, and this task is required for one of our products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this based on your comments:

**Version 2.0**
Code may need refactoring but I think it is the solution you are looking for:

```
var obj1= [{/* Based on updated sample code */ }];

        function getCount(obj2){
            var res = obj2.reduce(function(res,node){ return res += Object.keys(node).reduce(
                function(res,value){
                    if (value==="childs"){
                        res +=2 + getCount(node[value]);
                        res -= obj2.filter(function(n){  return Object.keys(n).some(function(propName){ return propName ==="childs"; }); }).length;
                    }
                    return res;
                },0 );
            },0);
            return res;
        }
        console.log('Show Levels')
        for(var i=0;i<obj1.length;i++){
            console.log( 'Object =>',obj1[i].name, " level= ", getCount([obj1[i]]));
        }
```

**Version 1.0**

```
  var parent1= [{
        name:"Node Parent 2",
        childs:[{
            name:"Sub Node 2"
        },
            {
                name:"Sub Node 3",
                childs:[{
                    name:"Sub Sub Node 1"
                },{
                    name:"Sub Sub Node 2",
                    childs:[{
                        name:"Sub Sub Sub Node 1"
                    },{
                        name:"Sub Sub Sub Node 2"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
    }];

    function getCount(obj2){
        var res = obj2.reduce(function(res,node){ return res += Object.keys(node).reduce(
            function(res,value){
                if (value==="childs"){ res +=1 + getCount(node[value]); }
                return res;
            },0 );
        },0);
        return res;
    }

    console.log("final count", getCount(parent1));
```

Comment: For some reason it throw the result of every time it appears but no total for parent 1 and parent 2 of main object

Comment: I think I am missing the point you only want the total count per parent?

Comment: I call parent to this [ {/*Parent 1*/}, {/*Parent 2*/}]. Then i want the total of the most deep object for each parent

Comment: I've fixed the code for better understanding. Result most be: "Node Parent 1 Level 0" => 2 Levels and "Node Parent 1 Level 0" => 4 Levels. Is the lowest level by each node parent.